# CGAL triangle association with Facet_iterator and primitive ID

Tags: c++, cgal

I'm trying to associate CGAL Polyhedron_3 triangle facets with Primitive::ID to an array of facets got by iterating using Facet_iterator.

I have a Polyhedron_3 triangle mesh created from an .off file by using the `read_off()` function. Now, I'm using an AABB_tree to find the closest triangle to a point. I'm successfully applying `AABB_tree::closest_point_and_primitive()`. However, I could not find a way to convert the Primitive::Id to an integer corresponding to the facet.

To make it clear why I need this integer number: I'm using Polyhedron::Facet_iterator to export all triangles to an array for visualization. In another array I would like to save information from the closest point search. To access the right position, I need the corresponding ID from Primitive::ID as integer.

I found a possible solution [here](http://cgal-discuss.949826.n4.nabble.com/Getting-index-of-facet-closest-to-a-point-tp4657635p4657648.html) and tried to implement it without success.

In my MeshModel class I'm getting the Facet_iterator:

```
Polyhedron::Facet_iterator MeshModel::getFacetIterator() {
  return P_.facets_begin();
}
```

After using `closest_point_and_primitive()`:

```
cgal::Polyhedron::Facet_iterator iterator = mesh_model->getFacetIterator();
int triangle_id = &(*ppid.second) - &(*iterator);
associations.triangles_to.push_back(triangle_id);
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here or if there's a better solution to get integer values between 0 and "number of faces". And I can not find any documentation about what Primitive::Id really is.

This is the error message I currently get:

```
error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘associations::Associations::triangles_to’, which is of non-class type ‘int [0]’
     associations.triangles_to.push_back(triangle_id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution using

`typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel, CGAL::Polyhedron_items_with_id_3> Polyhedron;`

After reading in the .off file, I'm setting the ID

```
std::size_t i = 0;
for (Polyhedron::Facet_iterator facet = P_.facets_begin(); facet != P_.facets_end(); ++facet) {
    facet->id() = i++;
  }
```

And then, after closest_point_and_primitive(), I'm getting the ID using the Primitive::ID, which is actually a Facet_handle:

```
int getFacetIndex(Polyhedron::Facet_handle &handle) {
  int facet_id;
  facet_id = handle->id();
  return facet_id;
}
```